# Get the favicon of a url and display it (firefox web-ext)

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am working on a Firefox web-ext. Is there a way by which I can get the favicon of the current website/tab. I referred to [this](https://jmperezperez.com/console-log-favicon/) but I don't think the `%c` works anymore.This is my manifest.json (part of it) :

```
"permissions": [
  "storage",
  "<all_urls>",
  "tabs",
  "activeTab"
],

"browser_action": {
  "default_icon": "icons/love.ico",
  "default_title": "Show URL and Favicon",
  "default_popup": "popup/addsite.html"
}
```

The `addsite.js` file looks like this :

```
var addnewsite = document.querySelector('.addnewbutton');
var siteContainer = document.querySelector('.site-container');
addnewsite.addEventListener('click', addNEWsite);

function onError(error) {
  console.log('Error: ${error}');
}//generic error handler

function addNEWsite(){
    siteurl();
    function siteurl(){
        browser.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true, active: true }, function (tabs) {
            addurl(tabs[0].url);
        });
    }
    function addurl(link){
        var urltostore = link;
        var gettingItem = browser.storage.local.get(urltostore);
        gettingItem.then((result) => {
            var objTest = Object.keys(result);
            if(objTest.length < 1 && urltostore !== ''){
                storeurl(urltostore);
            }
        }, onError);
    }
}

function storeurl(link){
    var storingurl = browser.storage.local.set({link});
    storingurl.then(() => {
        displayurl(link);
    }, onError);
}

function displayurl(link) {
    var url = document.createElement('div');
    var urlDisplay = document.createElement('div');
    var urlPara = document.createElement('p');
    url.setAttribute('class','url');
    urlPara.textContent = link;
    urlDisplay.appendChild(urlPara);
    url.appendChild(urlDisplay);
    siteContainer.appendChild(url);
}
```

Here is a snapshot when the button inside the extension is clicked:

[image: (picture)].

You can see that I can get the url using the present code. But I also want to show the favicon of the page beside its url (favIconUrl shows the url of the icon, can i get it from there!?, if yes,how?). Can anyone help me out in doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who need the code for this, here it is:

```
var favicon = document.createElement('img');
// get the url of favicon using favIconUrl function
favicon.src = "https://jsfiddle.net/favicon.ico";
document.body.appendChild(favicon);
// you can also append it to a container if you want to
```

Check out the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Miraj50/4301mLvg/) for this.

For getting the url of the favicon, one can either append `/favicon.ico` at the end or get it from the [favIconUrl](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/Tab).

Answer (score 1):

The favicon of a website can be found in one of two ways.  In the `<head>` section you can find:

```
<link rel='shortcut icon' type='image/x-icon' href='/favicon.ico' />
```

Where the href attribute points to the favicon.  If this is missing, then it will always be /favicon.ico, in the root of the website.

Comment: Can you please be more precise as to where do I have to put it so that I can "appendChild" it to the required div-container?

Answer (score 1):

A great hooray for https://icons.better-idea.org/ who have created a solution for the fact that less & less favicon are stored at the root of a domain.

It is free, it works (so far 100% of the time in my case) and it is as simple as it can be :

```
<img src='https://icons.better-idea.org/icon?url=github.com&size=80..120..200' />
```

you may want to bookmark the github repo if you don't want to rely on a free webservice that could stop anytime (as he points out rightfully in the website) https://github.com/mat/besticon

clap clap

### EDIT 2022

the dev doesn't keep a server to host this service anymore, you'll have to host it yourself :

https://github.com/mat/besticon#hosting

Comment: It's not working, please update the url

Comment: @HarryAdel happy ?

Comment: Google provides a similar service: `https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=${domain}&sz=256`

Comment: @MoritzRingler f$ck g00-bigBrother-gle :)

Answer (score 0):

Had to look at options for getting the favicon recently, and a more detailed answer would have helped me. So here we go:

##### How the browser does it

From what I gathered, favicons are provided in three ways:

- as a URL in the `href` attribute of a icon link tag in the header: `<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" sizes="72x72"/>`
- as inline data in  the `href` attribute of a icon link tag in the header: `<link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="data:image/svg+xml,..."/>`
- if no link tag is provided in the header, browsers will look for a file `favicon.ico` at the root

A long time ago, browsers could only use ICO files, which is a container for one or more bitmap images (BMP or PNG). Today, using `.png` files directly is as popular (it seems to be half and half). It is also possible to use SVG files.

Several sizes can be provided, either through an ICO containing multiple bitmaps of different sizes, or by giving multiple icon link tags with different [`size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link#attr-sizes) attribute values. The browsers then picks the one it finds most suitable.

If you want to do it like the browser, you have to look for icon link tags, possibly filtering by the size attribute, and if you find one, figure out if it is a URL or an inline image. If none is found, you should try the default icon at the root URL.

##### In background scripts with "tabs permission"

Apart from checking icon links and fallback, web extensions offer two additional ways to get the current favicon in background scripts, if the extension has the "tabs" permission:

- through the [`tabs.Tab`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/Tab) object, which has a `favIconUrl` property (note that setting this property does not update the favicon):

```js
const tabs = await browser.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true })
const faviconUrl = tabs?.length > 0 ? tabs[0].favIconUrl : null
```

- by listening to [tabs.onUpdated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/onUpdated), which notifies about changes to favicon (the event will be triggered when the icon has loaded, not when the URL is detected):

```js
browser.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(
  (tabId, changeInfo, tab) => console.log('got favicon as ', changeInfo.favIconUrl), 
  {properties:['favIconUrl']}
)
```

(I found this particularly helpful when changing the favicon, as the initial icon will still be set when loaded, even if you have set a different one in the meantime, and the listener is the only way to detect that reliably)

The tabs API will provide you with the currently used favicon, but you might miss a size that works better for you.

##### Public APIs

Finally, there are several public APIs that provide a lookup service for favicons, which might be the most convenient option, at the cost of another fetch:

```html
Google:
<img src="https://s2.googleusercontent.com/s2/favicons?domain=stackoverflow.com&sz=32"/>

DuckDuckGo:
<img src="https://icons.duckduckgo.com/ip3/stackoverflow.com.ico"/>

Icon Horse:
<img src="https://icon.horse/icon/stackoverflow.com"/>
```

(please don't think of the ones above as recommendations, you might find a better or more suitable one for you when searching the web)

And there you go, this is all I know about favicons. Hope it helps.